# Ruby on Rails app : from Heroku to a local server : what are the main steps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, local

My Ruby on Rails app (basically a commenting and voting system) has been deployed and currently runs on Heroku. I need to deploy it on a local server to ensure an optimal performance for a customer-organized event in a location where the internet bandwidth is too low and unpredictable to support the 100+ simultaneous users.

Just as Ruby, Rails, Javascript, JQuery, AJAX and CSSs were new to me a few months ago, going local is something new I need and am eager to learn (which should also allow me to deploy onto a dedicated or virtual private server if needed).

The following elements are obviously on the way : choosing an operating system, installing Ruby on Rails, a web server, a database engine and deploying my app code and data of course but I need help to make sure I do not forget anything and really understand how all of these elements must be tied together to get my app running.

At a reasonably high level, starting with my app code, could you please share your experience and tell me the steps I need to take from scratch to have it run on a local server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Mac, then you're already most of the way there.  I do all of my Rails development on OS X.  The steps from there are pretty easy.

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).  This will help you quickly install any dependencies on the Mac that your Rails app needs (such as a database).  Since you're on Heroku, you're likely using Postgres.  So with Homebrew, you can install Postgres via `brew install postgresql`.
2. Copy your app code somewhere that makes sense.  I have all my apps inside my `~/Projects` directory.
3. **Recommended**:  Install [RVM](http://rvm.io).  This will help keep gemsets unique to projects and keep your global gemset clean.
4. If you're using bundler, do `bundle install` within your app's directory.
5. Within the app directory, do: `rake db:setup` (**Note**: This may require prepending `bundle exec`)
6. Start your server.  I tend to use [Unicorn](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails) (see [Heroku's deployment with Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) for even more details), so this would just be `unicorn`.  Else, `rails s` works as well.

Those are the high level steps to get a local server running.

Comment: Thank you @Cdub. One server option I have for this event is a Dell server with Ubuntu I believe. Will the process be roughly the same as on a Mac ? Also, when looking at your 6th step where the web server is started, I was wondering : does it have to be specifically installed (I mean locally, not on Heroku...) or is it part of Homebrew ?

Comment: The server either comes with Rails (`rails s`) or you can use a gem like `unicorn`.

As for will, it be similar, yes.  Instead of `homebrew` you'd use `apt-get install` for any dependencies you'd need.

Comment: @Pierre did this help?  If it did, please close this question by clicking the checkbox next to this answer. :)